# "javac: file not found:" when compiling file on Mac

Tags: java, compilation, terminal

I am trying to learn Java on MacBook Pro, but am not even sure how to compile or run a program and keep getting the following in Terminal:

```
javac: file not found: Example.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

when I enter my first code for Example.java saved in Text Edit.  The code I entered into Text Edit is

```
/* 
This is a simple Java program. 
Call this file Example.java. 
*/ 
class Example { 
// A Java program begins with a  call to main (). 
public static void main (String args[]) { 
System.out.println ("Java drives the web."); 
} 
}  
javac Example.java  
java Example
```

I have found info saying to set up a class path, but am not sure how to do this. Please keep everything as simple as possible.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but you're never going to learn Java in a couple days. Unless your interview's in a couple of month, or you have at least working knowledge of C, C++, C# (or some other related-ish language), you'll be over your head if the interviewers are the least bit competent. You'd probably be better off admitting you don't really know it and showing you've at least tried to get the basics.

Comment: Mat, Thanks and you are definitely right. They know I'm not even close to proficient. I just want enough to show I can learn. I wasn't navigating to the right directory, but I've got it now and am off and running!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your Java file is saved as Example.java (case matters), and that it is in the current directory (.).

You should be able to compile it then with javac Example.java as per your example.

But, to make sure you can compile with (these are basically the 'default' options):

```
javac -sourcepath .  -d . Example.java
```

When you run the class with:

```
java -cp . Example
```

Comment: Thanks rolfl, I'm not sure what sourcepath is, but it worked by navigating to the directory cd ~/Desktop/ Is sourcepath the same thing? Thanks again for answering!

Answer (score 1):

If none of these solutions are working and you are using Monterey 12.3.1, try going to settings > system & privacy find your terminal and files and folders and make sure to unlock them for access.

Comment: This is an underrated comment.. it solved my problem.

In MacOS some folders (like Downloads) cannot by default be used by Java (for security reasons!)

Answer (score 0):

The `javac` command only searches for files within the default java PATH and the current directory.  Make sure that you've already navigated to the directory that holds `Example.java` using the `cd` command before trying to compile.

For example, if the file's located on the Desktop:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
javac Example.java
java Example
```

Comment: Thanks Snowsickle, This is what I get when I try what you suggested.

Comment: MacBook-Pro:Desktop kerrimartin$ javac Example.java
Example.java:12: error: class, interface, or enum expected
cd ~/Desktop/
^
1 error

Comment: you're entering these as separate lines right?  The code in Example.java should end after your second closing brace, and not include the javac/java lines.  Those are entered later to compile and run in terminal and should not be part of your source code.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why it didn't work the first time, but it's working now.